# Lambda Functions - Python

Tags: python, lambda

I need help for this task. I have to write:

two assignment statements that respectively assigns to the variable SQUARE the lambda term that squares the argument , and assigns to the variable ODD the lambda term that tests if its argument is an odd number.

Comment: This is a problem statement, not a question. What have you tried so far and what's your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, that's now how we ask questions here. Please post a code that demonstrates your minimal efforts. Also please visit the [**help center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to better understand how things work here.

Comment: I have no idea how to program this. could someone please help me with how to code this.

Comment: This isn't really a "please do my homework for me" site. You need to demonstrate some effort and show us where you are stuck. Then we'll be glad to help you make progress.

Comment: Okay, well what I have so far is

Comment: def square(x): if x%2 == 0 then print "a is even" else : print"a is odd"

Answer (score 1):

A python lambda function looks like the following:

```
double = lambda x: x*2
```

It is a quick way to write a one-line function and is just shorthand for:

```
def double(x):
    return x*2
```

Google "python lambda" and you will find tutorials and more examples.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood I came up with the following code.Hope it helps

```
numbers = range(5)             ## few range of numbers
for i in numbers:
    square = lambda x: x*x     ## returns the square of each value in numbers
    print square(i)            ## prints the square of each value in numbers
for j in numbers:
    odd = lambda y: y%2 !=0    ## checks if odd or even 
    print odd(j)               ## print True if divisible (meaning its even number) or False (meaning its odd)
```